# Background-Sync on Chrome for Android Requires Service-Worker Restart to Sync

Tags: workbox

**Library Affected**:
workbox-sw, workbox-background-sync

**Browser & Platform**:
*E.g. Google Chrome 70 for Android*

**Issue**:
*When using background sync on chrome desktop, everything is working PERFECTLY. When I move over to a mobile device, background sync wont fire until I go into `chrome://serviceworker-internals` and restart the worker. Isn't this supposed to work in mobile chrome? Background sync api is supported for chrome on android.*

Everything is supported on https://www.caniuse.com

Here is the code on github.

https://github.com/kdesimini/httpsprototypingtest

### Service-worker.js

```
importScripts('workbox-3.6.3/workbox-sw.js');
workbox.setConfig({
    debug: false,
    modulePathPrefix: 'workbox-3.6.3/'
});
workbox.skipWaiting();
workbox.clientsClaim();
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute([]);    
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
    /(http[s]?:\/\/)?([^\/\s]+\/)/,
    workbox.strategies.networkOnly({
        plugins: [
            new workbox.backgroundSync.Plugin('requestsQueue', {
            maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60 // Retry for max of 24 Hours
                })
            ]
        }),
    'POST'
)
```

---

### workbox-config.js

```
module.exports = {
    "globDirectory": "dist/testyo/",
    "globPatterns": [
        "index.html",
        "*.js",
        "*.css"
        ],
        "dontCacheBustUrlsMatching": new RegExp('.+\.[a-f0-9]{20}\..+'),
        "maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes": 5000000,
        "swSrc": "src/service-worker.js",
        "swDest": "dist/testyo/service-worker.js"
};
```

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: Vinod, I have not. I abandoned workbox and went with another solution.